# Query sheet and return Column Headers that match two criteria in a row

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I am trying to return an array of column headers based on TRUE values and Item names.

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMxyTpLk5ixldcbPwehMqFz7vfEnTy4fkgRgcdDH3WM/edit?usp=sharing) <- Clicky

**Sheet 2:**

[image]

**Sheet 1:** (desired results)

[image]

I think I am close but can't rack my brain to search for both TRUE values within the corresponding Item and return the headers for each. I have tried the following but it returns nothing. It is as far as I have gotten.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(Sheet2!A1:D,"Select * where G='"&A1&"'",1),"Select Col1 where Col2 is not null"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Sheet2!A2:D=TRUE, SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1:D1, " ", "♦"), )),,9^9))), " "), "♦", " "))
```

[image]

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {Sheet2!G2:G, 
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Sheet2!A2:D=TRUE, SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1:D1, " ", "♦"), )),,9^9))), " "), "♦", " "))}, 
 {2,3,4,5}, 0)))
```

Comment: Although I was hoping my query approach was close because I can understand it much easier this is flawless. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I apologize I just realized it does not take into consideration Column A listings, I need it to depend on what Column A says and match that string item for item. This detail was not considered when I made the post because my thought process and trial formula was already in that mindspace.

Comment: @KevinP. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in another way, I did find a solution utilizing a preferred method of sticking with minimal functions that I have a better understanding of, I was simply missing the transpose function.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:$G,"Select * where G = '"&$A1&"'",1)),"Select Col1 where Col2 = TRUE"))
```

The only unfortunate part is I cannot seem to get it to expand down but it will return the results horizontally in a cell. It is also MUCH faster.

To get the results separated by comma's in a single row you could use **JOIN**:

```
=JOIN(", ",TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:$G,"Select * where G = '"&$A1&"'",1)),"Select Col1 where Col2 = TRUE")))
```